# How to print from nested map in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to print score value only

```
    void main() {
           List questions =  [
            {
              'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
              'answers': [
                {'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
                {'text': 'Red', 'score': 0},
                {'text': 'Green', 'score': 0},
                {'text': 'White', 'score': 0},
              ],
            },
          ];
```

I tried to do

```
print(questions[0]["score"])
```

But it doesn't work. can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `questions[0]` you are getting the first element in the array, which in this case is:

```dart
{
  'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
  'answers': [
    {'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
    {'text': 'Red', 'score': 0},
    {'text': 'Green', 'score': 0},
    {'text': 'White', 'score': 0},
  ],
}
```

When you then write `questions[0]["score"]` you are trying to get the key `score`, which as you can see is `null`.

You should instead access `answers` inside the object, take a look at the examples below:

```dart
print(questions[0]["score"]); // null
print(questions[0]['answers'][0]['score']); // 10
print(questions[0]['answers'].map((answer) => answer['score'])); // (10, 0, 0, 0)
```